# Geeetech Prusa I3 Pro W. Cannot update firmware

Tags: prusa-i3, diy-3d-printer, geeetech

Initially when I built it, it turned on and the LCD worked. I had an issue with the Z axis but I think that's unrelated to my current issue.

The next day when powering on the LCD just showed black squares.

I contacted Geeetech who suggested replugging the LCD, removing the A4998 and testing or updating the firmware with Arduino 1.0.1.

The first 2 had no effect so I tried the firmware.

I've installed Arduino and have the right firmware, but the issue I'm having is it doesn't look like anything is passing from my laptop to the GT2560 board when I upload. The error message I am getting is:

```
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
```

I have 2 green LEDs on, one next to the USB and one next to the power, and an orange LED near the CPU. None flash when I try to upload the script. I cannot also burn a bootloader, getting an "usb not found" error.

I've tried other things I've seen online, such as pressing reset just after trying to upload - this doesn't work either.

I'm laptop runs ubuntu, and I've also tried with a windows PC.

Any ideas ?

> Hi Andrew and welcome to 3D Printing.SE! This happened to me before, usually it is related to the USB port not being available or in use by another program. Please look into this or this and update your question by edit that you tried those answers. – 0scar 1 hour ago

I have tried the above links and don't find anything that helps.

Main points:

- I don't see a flashing LED at any point.
- I have tried pressing reset when uploading - this hasn't helped.
- I have tried to burn a bootloader - again, I get an "usb not found" error.

If it helps, I've also unplugged everything else from my 3D printer that was connected to the GT2560 other than USB and Power.

Comment: Hi Andrew and welcome to 3D Printing.SE! This happened to me before, usually it is related to the USB port not being available or in use by another program. Please look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645441/avrdude-stk500v2-receivemessage-timeout/29135050) or [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/33505/why-do-i-get-avrdude-stk500v2-receivemessage-timeout-error-when-uploading-to?newreg=95d2567ee8bc4b3dbc5ce62a6efb9e7b) and update your question by [edit] that you tried those answers.